# How to color arrows in ggbiplot?

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot, ggrepel

I am doing a PCR analysis and I was wondering if there is a possibility to colour the arrows based on some features? Like in my example, I would like to have half of the arrows colored in red (WT), and the other in blue (SHC). Is that possible?
Or maybe I can some how make it more readable by repel the text of the arrow? I was thinking of using ggrepel function but it is hard to implement it to ggbiplot.

Thank you for your help!
Best,
Magda
Here is my plot: [image: PCA]

```
align_test <-structure(list(`PC [32:1]_WT` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 
7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 8L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.190123303", 
" 0.192143584", " 0.197620250", " 0.205793279", " 0.218097809", 
" 0.225827220", " 0.237395528", " 0.26544825", " 0.292774628", 
"1", "32", "PC [32:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [32:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.092040068", " 0.102566839", " 0.134681434", " 0.136438126", " 
0.141535981", " 0.151006936", " 0.174595557", " 0.17863360", " 0.195910880", 
"2", "32", "PC [32:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:1]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names 
= c("type", "lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", 
"X20C.1", "X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.028618787", " 0.064136083", " 0.073067505", " 0.107256117", " 
0.109169315", " 0.110132544", " 0.296655942", " 0.298069144", " 0.30350532", 
"1", "34", "PC [34:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names 
= c("type", "lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", 
"X20C.1", "X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.831784332", " 0.853554543", " 0.979207564", " 0.980610857", " 
0.986071565", " 1.087151057", " 1.275408710", " 1.296358048", " 1.33507496", 
"2", "34", "PC [34:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:3]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 3.45674106", 
" 3.515092486", " 3.889646802", " 6.221964264", " 6.728083275", 
" 6.901576493", " 6.988847953", " 7.570982175", " 8.325405224", 
"3", "34", "PC [34:3]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:4]_WT` =  
 structure(c(13L, 
 12L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Names = c("type", 
 "lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
 "X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
 0.003608142", 
 " 0.009593605", " 0.01377619", " 0.640641234", " 0.646727566", 
 " 0.700966546", " 1.673981019", " 1.949321892", " 2.379120532", 
 "34", "4", "PC [34:4]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [36:2]_WT` = 
 structure(c(13L, 
 12L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
 "lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
 "X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
5.927665949", 
" 6.220126884", " 7.267489528", " 7.347447879", " 7.534377640", 
" 7.778419030", " 7.806013274", " 7.939279055", " 8.09846106", 
"2", "36", "PC [36:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [36:3]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Names 
= c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.028559666", 
" 0.03612411", " 0.038200850", " 0.749333689", " 0.749919197", 
" 0.755998081", " 1.808646353", " 1.828839542", " 2.402261775", 
"3", "36", "PC [36:3]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [36:4]_WT` = 
structure(c(11L, 
10L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.023226478", 
" 0.025114742", " 0.040478812", " 0.366984971", " 0.372919272", 
" 0.493759599", "0", "36", "4", "PC [36:4]", "WT"), class = "factor"), 
`PE [32:1]_WT` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.022006628", 
" 0.031819118", " 0.039866413", " 0.044215273", " 0.053551855", 
" 0.054495846", " 0.130729375", " 0.136588646", " 0.13726183", 
"1", "32", "PE [32:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PE [34:1]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.370147732", 
" 0.382074873", " 0.488762018", " 0.517572332", " 0.529107575", 
" 0.531161691", " 1.337458441", " 1.355766176", " 1.36578601", 
"1", "34", "PE [34:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PE [34:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
3.254514812", 
" 3.461519880", " 3.472679987", " 3.505874903", " 3.565597241", 
" 4.033434205", " 4.072396442", " 4.30163738", " 4.511385095", 
"2", "34", "PE [34:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PE [36:1]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.207274668", 
" 0.239641835", " 0.265345829", " 0.414085178", " 0.419013801", 
" 0.426680862", " 1.550312378", " 1.608387315", " 1.63696605", 
"1", "36", "PE [36:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PE [36:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c("2", 
"24.268192390", "25.374396380", "27.716059900", "27.745197630", 
"27.914192010", "29.114999640", "29.535402810", "29.75391108", 
"32.547493400", "36", "PE [36:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), 
`PE [36:3]_WT` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.132781401", 
" 0.137610076", " 0.14752789", " 2.458986152", " 2.485334246", 
" 2.502982662", " 6.817662081", " 6.928308393", " 9.010573736", 
"3", "36", "PE [36:3]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PG [32:1]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.002001495", 
" 0.007652133", " 0.010718190", " 0.014692247", " 0.016431819", 
" 0.024270096", " 0.114476974", " 0.12414996", " 0.126123941", 
"1", "32", "PG [32:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PG [34:1]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.190935979", 
" 0.387591051", " 0.388524011", " 0.535896614", " 0.542213086", 
" 0.545568613", " 1.273978384", " 1.27508424", " 1.352473950", 
"1", "34", "PG [34:1]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PG [34:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.804344486", 
" 1.731323933", " 1.789596755", " 1.915282873", " 1.958288132", 
" 1.990149785", " 2.703851782", " 2.75268505", " 2.927032022", 
"2", "34", "PG [34:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PG [36:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 3L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = 
c("14.920456650", 
"2", "30.94488151", "31.990711260", "32.429419490", "33.204884010", 
"33.362493370", "33.521605950", "33.544005870", "34.083943260", 
"36", "PG [36:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PG [36:3]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.09424408", 
" 0.104255836", " 0.105968260", " 0.190228801", " 0.199106893", 
" 0.207201072", " 0.238707192", " 0.486696579", " 0.501206419", 
"3", "36", "PG [36:3]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `CL [64:0]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.000854878", 
" 0.001144995", " 0.001387258", " 0.002088531", " 0.002197505", 
" 0.002421467", " 0.007613802", " 0.009523686", " 0.01147820", 
"0", "64", "CL [64:0]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `CL [68:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.317566463", 
" 0.322573070", " 0.329202368", " 0.345417305", " 0.347318908", 
" 0.392051405", " 0.410726550", " 0.420979104", " 0.46432611", 
"2", "68", "CL [68:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `CL [68:4]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.043189398", 
" 0.046278008", " 0.052017808", " 0.05430535", " 0.056822917", 
" 0.062392598", " 0.076091557", " 0.089433716", " 0.108661125", 
"4", "68", "CL [68:4]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `CL [70:4]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.246671197", 
" 0.255020360", " 0.265579988", " 0.30706685", " 0.310210558", 
" 0.321733033", " 0.327668171", " 0.376732525", " 0.401729495", 
"4", "70", "CL [70:4]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `CL [72:2]_WT` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
2.697381593", 
" 2.831744905", " 2.913409569", " 3.060426171", " 3.148227718", 
" 3.159879284", " 3.349649409", " 3.451885409", " 3.66024620", 
"2", "72", "CL [72:2]", "WT"), class = "factor"), `PC [32:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.024194075", 
" 0.033292421", " 0.034143090", " 0.037379618", " 0.046370335", 
" 0.046537814", " 0.350692159", " 0.352322952", " 0.36588136", 
"1", "32", "PC [32:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.209711058", 
" 0.223245816", " 0.224200025", " 0.269032866", " 0.269832912", 
" 0.276946813", " 0.780874116", " 0.798968660", " 0.81404751", 
"1", "34", "PC [34:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [32:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.241328020", 
" 0.242688412", " 0.26305241", " 0.530336618", " 0.545228619", 
" 0.550118773", " 0.555302395", " 0.574278665", " 0.589899895", 
"2", "32", "PC [32:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
1.740476244", 
" 1.803162091", " 1.817345954", " 1.830247326", " 1.860433594", 
" 1.889164168", " 2.337791445", " 2.353566549", " 2.49814340", 
"2", "34", "PC [34:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:3]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
2.318065488", 
" 2.42008308", " 3.008624094", "12.951792530", "13.521213310", 
"13.897807760", "13.966350770", "14.530307630", "14.555244600", 
"3", "34", "PC [34:3]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [34:4]_SHC` = 
structure(c(11L, 
10L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
1.477216116", 
" 1.555503259", " 1.587365867", " 3.075090535", " 3.151443881", 
" 3.271447573", "0", "34", "4", "PC [34:4]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), 
`PC [36:2]_SHC` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 7.926339304", 
" 8.127765888", " 8.145856956", "10.336521680", "10.338409490", 
"10.603633980", "11.485333950", "11.66138000", "11.787934800", 
"2", "36", "PC [36:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [36:3]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 2L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.019677993", 
" 0.03795715", " 1.048113389", " 1.063729033", " 1.106242090", 
" 2.332662214", " 2.444683502", " 2.485317522", "0", "3", 
"36", "PC [36:3]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PC [36:4]_SHC` = 
structure(c(11L, 
10L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.035217187", 
" 0.053871483", " 0.054853129", " 0.476764281", " 0.486651650", 
" 0.500819878", "0", "36", "4", "PC [36:4]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), 
`PE [32:1]_SHC` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 9L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.099703067", 
" 0.105351638", " 0.106481202", " 0.109530249", " 0.136223764", 
" 0.139493538", " 0.273600556", " 0.286062764", " 0.32636370", 
"1", "32", "PE [32:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PE [34:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.828353216", 
" 0.840820125", " 0.841293691", " 0.843389516", " 0.879185708", 
" 0.899771059", " 2.132484159", " 2.135781366", " 2.15590759", 
"1", "34", "PE [34:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PE [36:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.239187105", 
" 0.246945724", " 0.265123648", " 0.339317543", " 0.356743423", 
" 0.363542648", " 1.299719983", " 1.31303685", " 1.360446160", 
"1", "36", "PE [36:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PE [34:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
3.599205032", 
" 3.784135784", " 3.907420311", " 4.211765048", " 4.260504858", 
" 4.429725928", " 5.448459538", " 5.453957351", " 5.77536477", 
"2", "34", "PE [34:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PE [36:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = 
c("19.753412220", 
"19.827336700", "2", "20.217143020", "21.454080460", "21.854562810", 
"21.887561240", "25.600356340", "25.76911322", "26.267576570", 
"36", "PE [36:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PE [36:3]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.066723651", 
" 0.08617378", " 0.097660097", " 2.282177192", " 2.352372963", 
" 2.370187972", " 4.562355527", " 4.628999105", " 4.807042338", 
"3", "36", "PE [36:3]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PG [32:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.057459401", 
" 0.076627845", " 0.081694576", " 0.088996045", " 0.094928769", 
" 0.096305411", " 0.157085113", " 0.230766489", " 0.24512811", 
"1", "32", "PG [32:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PG [34:1]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
1.068817563", 
" 1.093343337", " 1.095969122", " 1.108710734", " 1.113733401", 
" 1.172543270", " 2.387306194", " 2.53513442", " 2.563435979", 
"1", "34", "PG [34:1]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PG [34:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
2.657542572", 
" 2.816543174", " 2.821974768", " 2.822367787", " 2.838485816", 
" 2.858851473", " 4.549409201", " 4.803167823", " 4.86824023", 
"2", "34", "PG [34:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `PG [36:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 9L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c("2", 
"31.769360460", "32.253984600", "32.337079360", "32.840808270", 
"32.979541120", "33.769722490", "34.562081930", "35.14862460", 
"36", "36.195185240", "PG [36:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), 
`PG [36:3]_SHC` = structure(c(13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 
9L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Names = c("type", "lipids", 
"length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", 
"X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 0.040180974", 
" 0.042743395", " 0.06000031", " 0.258924122", " 0.269743112", 
" 0.282326721", " 0.510969807", " 0.512886289", " 0.514560668", 
"3", "36", "PG [36:3]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `CL [66:0]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.004130378", 
" 0.004814308", " 0.006364221", " 0.006671769", " 0.007314019", 
" 0.011747384", " 0.015840778", " 0.02253961", " 0.023401093", 
"0", "64", "CL [66:0]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `CL [70:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.256862326", 
" 0.351954191", " 0.375693318", " 0.382326299", " 0.400344628", 
" 0.483097774", " 0.496309773", " 0.56177582", " 0.711819877", 
"2", "68", "CL [70:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `CL [74:2]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 8L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
1.707117768", 
" 1.810974482", " 1.964832118", " 2.495174754", " 2.537644531", 
" 2.548147974", " 2.612358054", " 2.67694279", " 3.454463141", 
"2", "72", "CL [74:2]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `CL [70:4]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.066796591", 
" 0.083028102", " 0.08893272", " 0.095727468", " 0.108896499", 
" 0.115997721", " 0.138971717", " 0.143615213", " 0.161909067", 
"4", "68", "CL [70:4]", "SHC"), class = "factor"), `CL [72:4]_SHC` = 
structure(c(13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Names = c("type", 
"lipids", "length", "DB", "X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", 
"X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", "early2", "early3"), .Label = c(" 
0.266602215", 
" 0.30617660", " 0.312034391", " 0.397538279", " 0.432116471", 
" 0.434049624", " 0.449779773", " 0.450839280", " 0.456267995", 
"4", "70", "CL [72:4]", "SHC"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("PC 
[32:1]_WT", 
"PC [32:2]_WT", "PC [34:1]_WT", "PC [34:2]_WT", "PC [34:3]_WT", 
"PC [34:4]_WT", "PC [36:2]_WT", "PC [36:3]_WT", "PC [36:4]_WT", 
"PE [32:1]_WT", "PE [34:1]_WT", "PE [34:2]_WT", "PE [36:1]_WT", 
"PE [36:2]_WT", "PE [36:3]_WT", "PG [32:1]_WT", "PG [34:1]_WT", 
"PG [34:2]_WT", "PG [36:2]_WT", "PG [36:3]_WT", "CL [64:0]_WT", 
"CL [68:2]_WT", "CL [68:4]_WT", "CL [70:4]_WT", "CL [72:2]_WT", 
"PC [32:1]_SHC", "PC [34:1]_SHC", "PC [32:2]_SHC", "PC [34:2]_SHC", 
"PC [34:3]_SHC", "PC [34:4]_SHC", "PC [36:2]_SHC", "PC [36:3]_SHC", 
"PC [36:4]_SHC", "PE [32:1]_SHC", "PE [34:1]_SHC", "PE [36:1]_SHC", 
"PE [34:2]_SHC", "PE [36:2]_SHC", "PE [36:3]_SHC", "PG [32:1]_SHC", 
"PG [34:1]_SHC", "PG [34:2]_SHC", "PG [36:2]_SHC", "PG [36:3]_SHC", 
"CL [66:0]_SHC", "CL [70:2]_SHC", "CL [74:2]_SHC", "CL [70:4]_SHC", 
"CL [72:4]_SHC"), row.names = c("type", "lipids", "length", "DB", 
"X13C.1", "X13C.2", "X13C.3", "X20C.1", "X20C.2", "X20C.3", "early1", 
"early2", "early3"), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a code I am using to generate the plot:

```
both_test <- align_test[5:13, ]
both_test[] <- lapply(both_test, function(x) {
if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x ###convert factor to 
numeric})
sapply(both_test, class)
both_test[is.na(both_test)] <- 0
align.type_test <- rownames(both_test)
prin_comp_wtshc <- prcomp(both_test, scale. = T)


g <- ggbiplot(prin_comp_wtshc, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
          labels  = align.type_test, 
          groups = align.type_test, ellipse = TRUE,  varname.size=2)

g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 15)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-15, 15))
g <- g + theme(legend.position = "none")
print(g)
```